# Getting error while deploying cert manager in gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

How to deploy cert manager in gke? How to create ssl certificate for ingress?

I try to deploy but getting error

How to deploy the cert manager in gke and create ssl certificate for ingress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the error received when you are trying to deploy and refer to this official [doc](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-with-cert-manager-on-google-kubernetes-engine-using-lets-encrypt-for-ingress-ssl/)

> From the above official doc you will learn how to deploy and configure
> cert-manager on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). You will learn how to
> configure cert-manager to get a signed SSL certificate from Let's
> Encrypt
>
> 1. Create a Kubernetes Cluster
> 2. Deploy a sample web server
> 3. Create a static external IP address
> 4. Create a domain name for your website
> 5. Create an Ingress
> 6. Install cert-manager
> 7. Create an Issuer for Let's Encrypt Staging
> 8. Re-configure the Ingress for SSL
> 9. Create a production ready SSL certificate

Refer to this [doc](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-with-cert-manager-on-google-kubernetes-engine-using-lets-encrypt-for-ingress-ssl/#troubleshooting) for troubleshooting steps for deploying cert manager in gke and and create ssl certificate for ingress and also